# wrapping setTimeout throwing error in IE9

Tags: javascript, settimeout, wrapper, apply

I have the following script which just wraps the setTimeout function.

```
var originalTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(fn, delay){
    originalTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
}

window.setTimeout(function(){}, 10);
```

The wrapping of window.setTimeout in IE9 is throwing an error saying

```
Object does not support property or method 'apply'
```

The script seems to be working on all other browsers. Can you help me with what is the problem?

Comment: Why not just do `originalTimeout(fn, delay)` ?

Comment: Internet Explorer 9, do not accept array-like objects and will throw an exception. It's not compatible. You can do the function call like Felix mentioned above

Comment: yeah, good point; IE9 doesn't accept the extra parameters to setTimeout anyway. i guess you can still pass them though, if you use that stuff...